# Between + plural or singular?

Tags: conjunctions, grammatical-number, singular-vs-plural

consider:

> we have node i.
>
> we have node j.
>
> there is a link between two nodes.

Please help me in below sentence.

> There is a link between **node(s)** i and j.

Plural or singular ? I have found both of them on google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We have a link between node**s** i and j.
>
> We have a link between node i and node j.

Note that if there were a third node, the links would be *among* them, not *between* them.

Comment: Yes. There are two nodes -- I and j. That makes it plural.